# How to parse a negative value String from a delimited CSV File

Tags: java, csv, numberformatexception, reader

I'm trying to read a comma delimited CSV file that displays the city, country, latitude and longitude in each row. The goal of my project is to print a statement that shows all cities in the southern hemisphere, which means reading the latitude of each row and converting those strings into integers. The problem is I keep getting a "NumberFormatException" while trying to parse the string, and I'm assuming its because some of these string numbers are negative values.

The latitude values the reader is converting are : 39, -57, -25, 35
The error throws a NumberFormatException at the input string latitude when all are proper integer, so I can only assume its because of the dash in the integers that stops it from parsing into a integer.

My code reads each line and splits it into tokens so I can evaluate each columns separately, and see if the parsed integer value of the latitudes are less than zero. This shows that the city with that latitude resides in the southern hemisphere and I can then add it to my ArrayList of cities that are in the Southern Hemisphere for me to print later.

```
    String path = args[0];
    String delimiter = ","; 
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)); 
      ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
      reader.skip(1); 
      while (reader.ready()) {
        String line = reader.readLine(); 
        String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter); 
        if (Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) < 0) {
          cities.add(tokens[0]);  
        }
      }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) is explicitly capable for handling a leading ASCII minus sign or a leading ASCII plus sign. Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace of the exception. It should tell you what the bad input was. You can also print `tokens[2]` or use a debugger to see what value is being parsed when the exception is thrown.

Comment: What you want is `String delimiter = "\\s*,\\s*";`

Comment: And to validate the token[2] string: `if token[2].matches("-?\\d+" && Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) < 0) {  cities.add(tokens[0]);  }`. This would ensure that the string value contained at index 2 of `tokens[]` array is a string representation of a signed or unsigned integer value and that value is less than 0, before it is added to the `cities` ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove whitespace before parsing

The error is not a result of the negative symbol ([HYPHEN-MINUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) character), but because of the [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (a [SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)) character, in your case).

If your input data is truly as you pasted in the question, your latitude token is not `"-25"`, it is:

```java
" -25"
```

… with a SPACE in front. Add a trim() before you attempt to parse, and you'll be all set.

```java
Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim())
```

---

Tip: To discover such non-obvious characters while [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging), you can get the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) and name of each character.

```java
String input = " -25" ;
input
    .codePoints()
    .mapToObj( (int codePoint) -> String.valueOf( codePoint ) + " = " + Character.getName( codePoint ) )
    .forEach( System.out :: println ) ;
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/r8chb4).

```
32 = SPACE
45 = HYPHEN-MINUS
50 = DIGIT TWO
53 = DIGIT FIVE
```

Comment: Or better yet: [`String#strip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()).

Answer (score 1):

Although Jacob found a likely problem, instead of creating your own parser use a mature library like [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

On this user guide page you can find several examples:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Comment: Queeg is really right. What's more, most good CSV APIs allow bean creation, so you would be able to create, say, a `City` object from each file line

Comment: CSV format looks simple but it's actually not just merely a comma separated text. It's tricky to handle the format. It is safer to use a mature library to handle CSV especially if the file come from external application.